# Extracting complex data from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to analyze some complex data which is in a Pandas DataFrame. I am not aware of the exact structure of the data inside the dataframe. I have pulled the data from a Json file. I used the "head" syntax to look at top level data.

If I want to extract the group manufacturer or nutrients in a seperate dataframe, how should I go about doing that so that I can do some Statistical analysis.

```
with open("nutrients.json") as f:
    objects = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
df = pd.DataFrame(objects) 
print(df.head())

            group manufacturer  \
0  Dairy and Egg Products                
1  Dairy and Egg Products                
2  Dairy and Egg Products                
3  Dairy and Egg Products                
4  Dairy and Egg Products                

                                                meta  \
0  {'langual': [], 'nitrogen_factor': '6.38', 're...   
1  {'langual': [], 'nitrogen_factor': '6.38', 're...   
2  {'langual': [], 'nitrogen_factor': '6.38', 're...   
3  {'langual': [], 'nitrogen_factor': '6.38', 're...   
4  {'langual': [], 'nitrogen_factor': '6.38', 're...   

                                                name  \
0  {'long': 'Butter, salted', 'sci': '', 'common'...   
1  {'long': 'Butter, whipped, with salt', 'sci': ...   
2  {'long': 'Butter oil, anhydrous', 'sci': '', '...   
3  {'long': 'Cheese, blue', 'sci': '', 'common': []}   
4  {'long': 'Cheese, brick', 'sci': '', 'common':...   

                                           nutrients  \
0  [{'code': '203', 'value': '0.85', 'units': 'g'...   
1  [{'code': '203', 'value': '0.85', 'units': 'g'...   
2  [{'code': '203', 'value': '0.28', 'units': 'g'...   
3  [{'code': '203', 'value': '21.40', 'units': 'g...   
4  [{'code': '203', 'value': '23.24', 'units': 'g...   

                                            portions  
0  [{'g': '227', 'amt': '1', 'unit': 'cup'}, {'g'...  
1  [{'g': '151', 'amt': '1', 'unit': 'cup'}, {'g'...  
2  [{'g': '205', 'amt': '1', 'unit': 'cup'}, {'g'...  
3  [{'g': '28.35', 'amt': '1', 'unit': 'oz'}, {'g...  
4  [{'g': '132', 'amt': '1', 'unit': 'cup, diced'...
```

Comment: Is possible create sample of json and use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html)?

Comment: I have edited with the code for loading tha Json file in python. What are you suggesting actually?If you can elaborate please?

Comment: You need to find out the structure of the data. Start by inspecting `df.columns`, `df["meta"]`, `df["nutrients"]`, etc. Looks like the latter are lists of dictionaries, so you'll need to think a little more about how you want to manage this data. What's wrong with working with the json structures directly?

Comment: Sure, but I need valid sample of json, can you add it to question?